# Daylight Savings Time "bug"

Tags: datetime, wolfram-mathematica

Here's a calculation of the number of hours between two consecutive days:

```
(AbsoluteTime[{2011, 3, 14}] - AbsoluteTime[{2011, 3, 13}]) / 3600
```

So you might not be surprised that Mathematica returns `24`.
But it is surprising. Every other programming language will say 23 because March 13 was the start of Daylight Savings Time.
I need my Mathematica program to be consistent with other languages in this regard.
What would you recommend?

To be clear about the problem: `AbsoluteTime[{2011,3,13}]` gives `3508963200`. Subtract the unix epoch and that's a unixtime of `1299988800`. But give that unixtime to any other programming language and ask it what date it corresponds to and it will say March 12 instead of March 13.
(The same thing will work fine for March 14.)

(OK, I know you're dying to know why I'd want to conform to all those clearly broken languages.
Well, first of all, the other languages have a point: Thanks to "springing ahead", midnight on March 14 was 23 hours after midnight on March 13.
Why I actually care: We use unixtime as the canonical representation for dates. So when I want to convey "2011-03-13 00:00 EST" to another program I send AbsoluteTime minus the unix epoch.
That works fine within Mathematica. When I convert that unixtime back I get "2011-03-13 00:00 EST" again.
But if I send that unixtime to another program it interprets it as "2011-03-12 23:00 EST" which turns out to be a problem, since that's the previous day.)

Comment: Daylight savings time is a horrible, horrible mess and it can in principle change every year in unpredictable ways depending on where you live. Any chance you could change your canonical representation to always use UTC and ignore DST?

Comment: I think you can find more answers joining the Mathematica usenet group

Comment: "`AbsoluteTime[]` uses whatever date and time have been set on your computer system. It performs no corrections for time zones, daylight saving time, etc."

Comment: (Also, you need to parenthesize the subtraction.  I tried to fix it but edits have to be at least six characters.)

Comment: (Thanks @Brett; fixed. When testing I just did it in seconds since I'm used to 86400 as the number of seconds in a day. Then I thought I might be weird in that regard and figured I should convert to hours.)

Comment: @Simon: The canonical representation (unixtime) does in fact ignore DST. The trouble is in converting to and from the human-readable version.

Comment: @dreeves I found no direct way to do that. Some time ago I made a few functions to adjust AbsoluteTime[] by TimeZone[], defining a Piecewise function based on date/time and location. Not very difficult to do, but cumbersome. I can't find the code now :(

Comment: If unixtime is non-DST, why do other programs not interpret it that way?  Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I tried to clarify in the question. (Which also kind of suggests an obvious work-around, which I guess I'll post as an answer.)

Comment: In my time zone (+1) DST started between Mar 26 and Mar 27. Your application has to know all the local rules to be universally useful.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Java to convert back and forth from Unix time:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
LoadJavaClass["java.util.Calendar"]

ToUnixTime[year_, month_, day_, hour_:0, minute_:0, second_:0] :=
  JavaBlock[
    Module[{calendar}
    , calendar = java`util`Calendar`getInstance[]
    ; calendar@set[year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second]
    ; Floor[calendar@getTimeInMillis[] / 1000]
    ]
  ]

FromUnixTime[time_Integer] :=
  JavaBlock[
    Module[{calendar}
    , calendar = java`util`Calendar`getInstance[]
    ; calendar@setTimeInMillis[time * 1000]
    ; calendar@getTime[]@toString[]
    ]
  ]
```

Sample use:

```
In[19]:= ToUnixTime[2011, 4, 26, 1, 2, 3]
Out[19]= 1303801323

In[20]:= FromUnixTime[1303801323]
Out[20]= "Tue Apr 26 01:02:03 MDT 2011"
```

As written, the preceding definitions will use your local time zone and locale settings in the conversions.

Comment: Ha, I was thinking about making a system call to a Ruby or Perl script. This is a bit better than that, I suppose! Thanks for providing the full code; that's super helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like this:

```
tzDreeves = {"Buenos Aires", "13 March", "13 September", 3, 4};

tZone[date_, tz_] := 
 Piecewise[{{tz[[4]],
   First@
    DateDifference[tz[[2]]<>" "<>DateString[date,"Year"], date, "Second"] > 0 &&
   First@
    DateDifference[tz[[3]]<>" "<>DateString[date,"Year"], date, "Second"] < 0}},
 tz[[5]]];

myTimeDif[d1_, d2_, tz_] := 
 DateDifference[DateList@AbsoluteTime[d1, TimeZone -> tZone[d1, tz]], 
                DateList@AbsoluteTime[d2, TimeZone -> tZone[d2, tz]], "Second"]


myTimeDif["March 13, 2011", "March 14, 2011", tzDreeves]
myTimeDif["March 12, 2011", "March 13, 2011", tzDreeves]
```

->

```
{82800,Second}  -> 23 hours
{86400,Second}  -> 24 hours
```

In the following example you can see the effect of the DS. We plot the time difference to a fixed date across the DST frontier:

```
data = Table[{
         DateList@DatePlus["March 12, 2011, 11PM", {i 10, "Minute"}], 
         First@myTimeDif[DatePlus["March 12, 2011, 11PM", {i 10, "Minute"}], 
                         "March 14, 2011, 2 AM", tzDreeves]},
       {i, 1, 13}];

DateListPlot[data, 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Day", "\n ", "Time"}, 
 GridLines -> {{{{2011, 3, 13}, Red}}, None}, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I posted a related question in comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica on 8/4/10:

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/6f50f6930f1ac325/

It turns out that there is (was?) a bug in the Mac version of M7 which essentially disregarded the Timezone specification in calls to AbsoluteTime.  I think the problem was fixed in M8, but I'm not certain.

Comment: @Cassini Welcome to StackOverflow! The spirit of this site is to make it as content-independent as we can. So, it is better to copy/paste than to link external resources when possible. This is of course not a strict rule, just a recommendation. Enjoy the site.

Comment: @Cassini With *Mathematica* 7.01 for the dates in [that post](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/6f50f6930f1ac325/) I get time difference in one hour as expected: `(AbsoluteTime[{2016, 04, 13, 3, 0, 0}] - AbsoluteTime[{2016, 04, 13, 2, 0, 0}])/3600` returns `1`.

Comment: @belisarius: Understood.  I'll avoid links in the future.

Comment: @Alexey: I believe the bug was Mac OS specific. What OS are you using?

Comment: I just confirmed that the bug was fixed in the Mac OS version of M8.

Comment: @Cassini I use OS Windows 2000 at the moment.

Comment: @belisarius Is linking really frowned upon? We do it all the time, don't we?

Comment: @Sjoerd **1)**An answer consisting in just a link is usually seen as a bad thing. **2)**An answer explaining something, and using a link as _bibliography_ is a good thing. -- Sometimes this "rules" are broken because the resource is copyrighted (but I've been frowned upon also in that situation, because copyright is usually not violated by copying a small portion), or plainly because the answerer does not understand the linked resource. Personally, I saw many times an accepted answer consisting only in a link, and the link is broken, turning the whole thing useless. continued ...

Comment: @Sjoerd you may search (or post a question) in meta if you need further clarification and different perspectives on this one